# /review leaderboard

Tags: feature-request, review

Why isn't there something like editor leader-board for /review?

Perhaps something that shows number of reviews, and a percentage actioned, or something similar. A simple way to rank users would just be reviews * percent actioned (though I am very open to suggestions).

As far as layout is concerned, I was thinking just ripping off the existing template for reputation, and showing both numbers (both reviewed and percent actioned, though not the breakdown).

I believe that this will help motivate some users to start using `/review` more frequently.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Oh, you mean something like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community

This will eventually replace /review and does include a leaderboard.

Comment: No, I don't. Very few people will ever be at the top, and so I am looking for something like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users but for reviewing

Comment: I should have linked:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/stats

Comment: I saw that, but there is no page two. There are just a few people listed.

Comment: @soandos the feature is three days old, give people time. There only _is_ one page.

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles, you mean there is no-one less than 7 [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/low-quality-posts/stats)? I don't believe it. Also, note when this was asked.

Comment: @soandos: Hmm, right, there are only 464 review on the page, but the total is 520.  In that case, your point is valid. The "when this was asked" part is irrelevant, I was responding to your replies on this comment (not the question itself) :)

Comment: Both the link in your answer and in the comment following it are dead - was it what later became the top 20 at, e.g., here?: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats